# How to show an UIAlertView (Or UIView) at the first launch of an Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uialertview

I would like to know how to show an UIAlertView or a UIView ONLY at the first launch of my application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `NSUserDefaults` to store a BOOL, like so:

```
-(void) showFirstRunAlerts {

    BOOL ranBefore = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"RanBefore"];

    if (!ranBefore) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:@"Message title."
                          message:@"Your message."
                          delegate:self
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks!"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"RanBefore"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
}
```

Comment: haha, I DO have to admit that when my coding starts to get sloppy, I think to myself, "but what if someone asks about this snippet on Stack?" so sad.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I do in my own app — except my VC conforms to `UIAlertViewDelegate` just to do more stuff but this is the basic first-launch mechanism behind it too. +1